# Writing a sentence starting with "To do so" in a semi-formal essay

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Can I start my essay with "To do so"? Does it sound too informal?

These are the sentences: the teacher could give a lecture ... To do so, they should train ...

Comment: How about "In order to do that, ..."?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly start a sentence with that phrase. To do so, however, is usually rather more formal than informal.